# finding wildcard entries efficiently

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map which contains strings as keys; those string resemble wildcards.

A key can have a `*` at the end, which means that when a lookup is performed, a string that has this key as a prefix shall match this key.

How can I efficiently retrieve the closest matching entry in such a map?

I tried sorting the map entries in a custom way and then using `lower_bound`, but that sorting does not produce the correct result:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const
    {
        if (lhs.size() < rhs.size()) {
            return true;
        }

        if (lhs.size() > rhs.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        bool isWildcardlhsAtEnd = (!lhs.empty() && lhs.back() == '*');
        bool isWildcardrhsAtEnd = (!rhs.empty() && rhs.back() == '*');

        if (isWildcardlhsAtEnd && isWildcardrhsAtEnd) {
            return lhs < rhs;
        }
        auto lhSubString = lhs.substr(0, lhs.size() - 1);
        auto rhsSubString = rhs.substr(0, rhs.size() - 1);

        if (isWildcardlhsAtEnd || isWildcardrhsAtEnd) {
            if (lhSubString == rhsSubString) {
                return !isWildcardlhsAtEnd;
            }
            else {
                return lhSubString < rhsSubString;
            }
        }

        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

template <typename Map>
void lookup(const Map& map, const std::string& key, int expected)
{
    auto it = map.lower_bound(key);
    if (it != map.end()) {
        std::cout << "found " << it->first << " for " << key << "; ";
        std::cout << "expected: " << expected << " got: " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "did not find a match for " << key << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int, Compare> map = {
        { "bar", 1 },
        { "bar*", 2 },
        { "foo1", 3 },
        { "bar1", 4 },
        { "bar1*", 5 },
        { "foo1*", 6 },
        { "bar12", 7 },
        { "bar12*", 8 },
        { "foo12", 9 },
        { "bar123", 10 },
        { "b*", 11 },
        { "f*", 12 },
        { "b", 13 },
        { "f", 14 }
    };

    std::cout << "sorted map \n------" << std::endl;
    std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [](const auto& e) { std::cout << e.first << std::endl; });
    std::cout << "-------" << std::endl;

    lookup(map, "foo1", 3);
    lookup(map, "foo123", 6);
    lookup(map, "foo", 12);
    lookup(map, "bar1234", 8);
}
```

This produces the following output which demonstrates the incorrect lookup:

```
sorted map 
------
b
f
b*
f*
bar
bar1
bar*
foo1
bar12
bar1*
foo12
foo1*
bar123
bar12*
-------
found foo1 for foo1; expected: 3 got: 3
did not find a match for foo123
found bar1 for foo; expected: 12 got: 4
did not find a match for bar1234
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c0f43b808954c0a)

I am also open to using another data structure if necessary.

Comment: You cant sort ab map.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong kind of data-structure for this, and that you might have to come up with your own that satisfies the requirements better than trying to force `std::map` to do something it was not really design ed for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude any suggestion?

Comment: @m.s.  Maybe a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Comment: There's a space overhead involved but one option is to create a prefix map. That is create a map that maps prefixes to collections with those prefixes. A map for "foo" and "foobar" would map "f" to "foo" and "foobar", "fo" to the same but "foob" to only "foobar". In essence you've pre-calculated all possible prefix searches! While technically scaling space linearly in string length (or longest prefix length) it can be prohibitively expensive for long strings. In which case you may succeed in a pre-match for (up to) the first 15 chars. But that trick relies on a good spread of prefixes.

Comment: @Persixty The lookup strings are not known a priori, so it cannot be precomputed.

Comment: @m.s. No but the strings to be looked up are! So if you add "foobar" to be found you actually add "f" , "fo", "foo", "foob", "fooba" and "foobar". Dreadful build cost but minuscule find cost! Alternative is a binary search tree. Find the prefix and all values 'below' are matches.

Comment: You seem to expect a "best match" behavior, where a wildcard match is weaker than an exact match. This conflicts with the strict weak ordering required for a std::map comparator. (I'm not sure if your `Compare` implementaiton even complies with the strict weak ordering requirement). @Persixty 's suggestion seems to be the best for not-too-long not too-many keys.

Comment: @peterchen It's a prefix requirement. So if they search for "f*" return a ready made collection of all 'entries' starting with "f" if they search "fo*" return a ready made collection of entries starting with "fo". Maybe up to some 'pre-built' length and second stage filtering for longer prefixes.

Comment: @Persixty sorry I still don't get it; if `foo*` is to be found, how would inserting `f`, `fo` and `foo` help if `foo123` is looked up?

Comment: @ms You've inserted that too! If any of your 'to be found' strings starts "foo"! Brute force pre-calculation of all non-empty searches! linear in time and space string length to build! Potentially constant time to look-up!

Comment: @Persixty as I already wrote, I do not know those strings before trying to look them up; I cannot insert all possible strings since the length is not restricted

Comment: @ms No. But you know the strings to be looked up or the problem doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Persixty maybe my description is unclear. I know e.g. that a valid string might start with `foo` (hence the entry's key is `foo*`); if any string, that starts with `foo` is looked up (such as `foo123` or `foo456`), I want the entry that corresponds to `foo*`

Comment: @ms. then you add "foo123" to "f", "fo", "foo", "foo1", "foo12", "foo123" and add "foo456" to "f", "fo", "foo", "foo4", etc. So searching for "foo" returns a colleciton with "foo123" and "foo456" in but searching for "foo1" returns a collection with only "foo123" in. You've anticipated all possible searches! it works brilliantly if modification is (relatively) rare.

Comment: @Persixty my problem is that I need to do a "reverse" lookup, please have a look at the example code above: `lookup(map, "foo123", 6);` this means I try to find the entry that matches `foo123` most closely. `foo123` is never inside the map

Comment: @ms Not sure what you mean by 'closest matching entry'. But to get all entries prefixed try this: http://ideone.com/YUjj6n. If you want 'closest matching' to me if nothing has the required prefix return the thing that matched the most characters then a binary search tree will help. Use the last valid node. If you want the shortest matching entry replace `std::set` with `std::string` and only store the shorter string or in a tie the lexicographically first. Or whatever 'closest' means.

Comment: @Persixty you still got it backwards. map contains `foo*`, then map is searched for `foo123`. "closest" means that if the map contains `{foo*, foo1*}`, then looking up `foo123` shall yield `foo1*`

Comment: @ms I've read the question 5 times and still can't see that it's saying that! I think your partial ordering needs a bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

If you separate the exact search and wildcard search, then the natural ordering works fine with strings. This code seems to produce the desired results (I think), and is efficient. The separate maps can be wrapped more conveniently of course.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
template <typename Map>
void lookup(const Map& exact ,const Map& wilds, const std::string& key, int expected)
{
    auto it = exact.find(key);

    if (it == exact.end()) {    // if not exact match   
        it = wilds.lower_bound(key);    // do best match 
        it--;
     }

        std::cout << "found " << it->first << " for " << key << "; ";
        std::cout << "expected: " << expected << " got: " << it->second << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> wilds = {
        { "bar*", 2 },
        { "bar1*", 5 },
        { "foo1*", 6 },
        { "bar12*", 8 },
        { "b*", 11 },
        { "f*", 12 }
    };
    std::map<std::string, int> exact = {
        { "bar", 1 },
        { "foo1", 3 },
        { "bar1", 4 },
        { "bar12", 7 },
        { "foo12", 9 },
        { "bar123", 10 },
        { "b", 13 },
        { "f", 14 }
    };
    lookup(exact , wilds, "foo1", 3);
    lookup(exact , wilds,"foo123", 6);
    lookup(exact , wilds,"foo", 12);
    lookup(exact , wilds,"bar1234", 8);
}
```